# Table element in CSS table-cell offsets other table-cell contents

Tags: html, css, css-tables

The following table element in the `"center"` div causes the contents in the `"left"` divs to be offset by several pixels from the top (8 in my browser). Adding some text prior to the table removes this offset.

Why? How do I stop this from happening without requiring a "dummy" line of text before my table?

```
<html>
<head>
    <style type="text/css">
        #left {
            display: table-cell;
            background-color: blue;
        }
        #menu {
            background-color: green;
        }
        #center {
            background-color: red;
            display: table-cell;
        }
    </style>
<body>
    <div id="left">
        <div id="menu">
            Menu 1<br>
            Menu 2<br>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="center">
        <table><tr><td>This is the main contents.</tr></td></table>
    </div>
    <div id="left">
        <div id="menu">
            Menu 1<br>
            Menu 2<br>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

### Update0

Note that with floats, I am unable to get a **centered** column expanding to its content. The source from which I extracted this example uses `display: table; margin-left: auto; margin-right: auto;` to center everything in the body.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I was able to fix it by adding `vertical-align:top;` to the '#left' style.

You should wrap the `display: table-cell` divs in another div with `display:table-row`

Comment: Ha!! Great, thanks. Thus ends about 3 hours extracting this little bit of evil by using Firebug.

Answer (score 0):

At a guess, I'd say you have a `margin-top` set on your `<table>`. Have a look in Firebug.

```
table {
margin-top: 0;
}
```

Any particular reason you're laying out like this? You can float divs and do advanced layouts without setting `display: table-cell`. Besides, tables should only be used for tabular data.

Comment: No, I've already poked around with firebug. It's a strange layout issue, and margins have nothing (that I'm aware of) to do with it. I've already tried just as you've suggested.